# C++ using Allegro5 in Visual Studio 2015 al_init_image_addon() error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, allegro5

I'm trying to start using allegro5 with C++. I copied the first code from a tutorial just to see if it'll work and here it is:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
int main()
{
    al_init();
    al_install_keyboard();
    al_init_image_addon();
    ALLEGRO_KEYBOARD_STATE klawiatura;
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *okno = al_create_display(320, 240);
    al_set_window_title(okno, "Allegro5 kurs pierwsze okno");
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *obrazek = al_load_bitmap("widok.png");
    while (!al_key_down(&klawiatura, ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE))
    {
        al_get_keyboard_state(&klawiatura);
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0));
        al_draw_bitmap(obrazek, 0, 0, 0);
        al_flip_display();
    }
    al_destroy_display(okno);
    al_destroy_bitmap(obrazek);
    al_rest(5.0);
    return 0;
    }
```

I keep getting the error

```
C861 identifier "al_init_image_addon" is undefined
```

Is there some kind of a new version of this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you didn't make it as a final answer.
Check if you imported the allegro image header.

```
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
```

In case you have Allegro with Visual Studio, you have to check the option Image addon in the next path: Project properties -> Allegro 5 -> Image Addon. Is a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

`al_init_image_addon` is defined in `allegro_image.h`. Add the following:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
```

Comment: now it shows 
`Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol__imp__al_init_image_addon referenced in function _main`

Comment: I installed it via Nuget and didn't check the option "Image Addon" in Project Proprieties->Allegro5,it works now ;)